# Entity Framework Core model one-to-one

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm working with EF Core 1.1 on an asp.net mvc core project and stumbled upon, what I think, is non optimal SQL generation. But hey, I'm not an expert so I might be completly wrong :)

**Models**

```
public class Influencer
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public Instagram Instagram { get; set; }

   public YouTube YouTube { get; set; }

   // In the future, more social channels will be added so
   // this is another concern I have how to architect/model properly
}

public class Instagram
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    // More properties such as bio, image url, website and other stuff
}

public class YouTube
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ChannelId { get; set; }
    // More properties such as bio, image url, statistics etc
}
```

The `UserId` and `ChannelId` are the "natural keys" (pardon my abuse of the correct SQL term :) and the `Id` properties "artifical keys" in a hope to create an interface/base class to simply various operations such as delete, refresh.

So to the question - how to correctly set this up in the `modelBuilder` to be correct?

The SQL I think should be the best is something like

```
Instagram
- Id (PK)
- UserId (AK)
- InfluencerId (FK)
YouTube
- Id (PK)
- ChannelId (AK)
- InfluencerId (FK)
Influencer
- Id
```

This should in effect constraint a one-to-one relationship between an influencer and its connected social platforms as well constraint that no influencer share the same social platform (just writing it make me unsure if I really want that since there might be cases where a couple for example share the same youtube-channel but are two individual influencers. Guess this is easier to achieve given the above design than introducing it later on)

On the the current modelling

```
modelBuilder
  .Entity<InstagramChannel>()
  .HasAlternateKey(i => i.UserId)
  .HasName("AK_UserId");

modelBuilder
  .Entity<Profile>()
  .HasOne<Instagram>()
  .WithOne()
  .HasForeignKey(typeof(Instagram), "ProfileId")
  .HasConstraintName("FK_Instagram_Profile")
  .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

This however generates a key to each of the social platforms on the `Influencer` such as `Influencer.InstagramId`, `Influencer.YouTubeId` causing two changes to database when a social platform is deleted.

**Edit**
So marking the properties `Instagram, YouTube` as not mapped produced the SQL that I was looking for. But now I'm uncertain whether or not I have missed something out - perhaps there is some optimizations enabled by EF core if the "parent table" has a direct relation to its related tables. Perhaps this just make it impossible for EF to evaluate the `Include(i => i.Instagram)` statement since it probably want to do so **without** the need for a join.

So quite a long post and perhaps not really a question (well, I said it :) and probably not suitable in this forum. But hey, there are many great guys and girls out there that might wan't to share their knowledge!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your goal even without using `modelBuilder`, using attributes:

```
public class Influencer
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

   [InverseProperty("Influencer")]
   public Instagram Instagram { get; set; }

   [InverseProperty("Influencer")]
   public YouTube YouTube { get; set; }
}

public class Instagram
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public int InfluencerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("InfluencerId")]
    public virtual Influencer Influencer { get; set; }
}

public class YouTube
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ChannelId { get; set; }

    public int InfluencerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("InfluencerId")]
    public virtual Influencer Influencer { get; set; }
}
```

You may remove `InfluencerId` properties if you don't like them (I prefer to have explicit Id field to be able to set int-value there instead of assigning `Influencer` instances and reading them from DB only for this).

Also, you may remove `virtual` keywords, because EF Core (currently) do not require them (but it also does not support LazyLoading yet, so I prefer to keep "virtual" in case it will be required later)

Comment: Thanks! Will try this out and it looks clean - less verbose then model builder syntax. Is it possible to add unique constraint using data annotations as well?

Comment: No, currently EF Core does not support `Index` attribute (but there is an [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4050) on github about adding it)